# LabelPropagation - How to avoid division by zero?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

When using [LabelPropagation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.semi_supervised.LabelPropagation.html), I often run into this warning (imho it should be an error because it completely fails the propagation):

> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/semi_supervised/label_propagation.py:279: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
>     self.label_distributions_ /= normalizer

So after few tries with the RBF kernel, I discovered the paramater `gamma` has an influence.

## EDIT:

The problem comes from [these lines](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f0ab589f/sklearn/semi_supervised/label_propagation.py#L274):

```
        if self._variant == 'propagation':
            normalizer = np.sum(
                self.label_distributions_, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
            self.label_distributions_ /= normalizer
```

I don't get how label_distributions_ can be all zeros, especially when its definition is:

```
self.label_distributions_ = safe_sparse_dot(
graph_matrix, self.label_distributions_)
```

Gamma has an influence on the graph_matrix (because graph_matrix is the result of _build_graph() that call the kernel function). OK. But still. Something's wrong

## OLD POST (before edit)

*I remind you how graph weights are computed for the propagation: W = exp(-gamma * D), D the pairwise distance matrix between all points of the dataset.*

The problem is: `np.exp(x)` **returns 0.0 if x very small**.
Let's imagine we have two points `i` and `j` such that `dist(i, j) = 10`.

```
>>> np.exp(np.asarray(-10*40, dtype=float)) # gamma = 40 => OKAY
1.9151695967140057e-174
>>> np.exp(np.asarray(-10*120, dtype=float)) # gamma = 120 => NOT OKAY
0.0
```

In practice, I'm not setting gamma manually but I'm using the method described in [this paper](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~jerryzhu/pub/CMU-CALD-02-107.pdf) (section 2.4).

## So, how would one avoid this division by zero to get a proper propagation ?

The only way I can think of is to **normalize the dataset in every dimension**, but we lose some geometric/topologic property of the dataset (a 2x10 rectangle becoming a 1x1 square for example)

---

#### Reproductible example:

In this example, it's worst: even with gamma = 20 it fails.

```
In [11]: from sklearn.semi_supervised.label_propagation import LabelPropagation

In [12]: import numpy as np

In [13]: X = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 10]])

In [14]: Y = [0, -1]

In [15]: LabelPropagation(kernel='rbf', tol=0.01, gamma=20).fit(X, Y)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/semi_supervised/label_propagation.py:279: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  self.label_distributions_ /= normalizer
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/semi_supervised/label_propagation.py:290: ConvergenceWarning: max_iter=1000 was reached without convergence.
  category=ConvergenceWarning
Out[15]: 
LabelPropagation(alpha=None, gamma=20, kernel='rbf', max_iter=1000, n_jobs=1,
         n_neighbors=7, tol=0.01)

In [16]: LabelPropagation(kernel='rbf', tol=0.01, gamma=2).fit(X, Y)
Out[16]: 
LabelPropagation(alpha=None, gamma=2, kernel='rbf', max_iter=1000, n_jobs=1,
         n_neighbors=7, tol=0.01)

In [17]:
```

Comment: maybe code the RBF kernel with a threshold to avoid the return of a 0.

Comment: But if I do such thing, a point at d=15 will have less influence than 2 point at d=100. (something like 1e-99 against 2*1e-99)

Comment: normally i would say lower the gamma but that won't help as you find it with an algo. People tend to take gamme = 1/n_features. 20 is really huge for a gamma. I'm not sure you'll ever bump into it while doing your LabelPropagation. With a Gamma<1 i think this would not be a problem.....can't help you more sorry.

Comment: 1/n_features clearly doesn't work for dataset like moons like `sklearn.datasets.make_moons(1000, noise=0.06)`

Comment: I think that values larger than 10 are awfully big, but that depends on your data of course. As for the `np.exp(x)` being zero for very small x, try this: `np.exp(np.asarray(-10*120, dtype=np.float128))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically you're doing a `softmax` function, right?

The general way to prevent `softmax` from over/underflowing is (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968722/how-to-implement-the-softmax-function-in-python))

```
# Instead of this . . . 
def softmax(x, axis = 0):
    return np.exp(x) / np.sum(np.exp(x), axis = axis, keepdims = True)

# Do this
def softmax(x, axis = 0):
    e_x = np.exp(x - np.max(x, axis = axis, keepdims = True))
    return e_x / e_x.sum(axis, keepdims = True)
```

This bounds `e_x` between 0 and 1, and assures one value of `e_x` will always be `1` (namely the element `np.argmax(x)`).  This prevents overflow and underflow (when `np.exp(x.max())` is either bigger or smaller than `float64` can handle).

In this case, as you can't change the algorithm, I would take the input `D` and make `D_ = D - D.min()` as this should be numerically equivalent to the above, as `W.max()` should be `-gamma * D.min()` (as you're just flipping the sign).  The do your algorithm with regards to `D_`

**EDIT:**

As recommended by @PaulBrodersen below, you can build a "safe" rbf kernel based on the `sklearn` implementation [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f0ab589f/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py#L815):

```
def rbf_kernel_safe(X, Y=None, gamma=None): 

      X, Y = sklearn.metrics.pairwise.check_pairwise_arrays(X, Y) 
      if gamma is None: 
          gamma = 1.0 / X.shape[1] 

      K = sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances(X, Y, squared=True) 
      K *= -gamma 
      K -= K.max()
      np.exp(K, K)    # exponentiate K in-place 
      return K
```

And then use it in your propagation

```
LabelPropagation(kernel = rbf_kernel_safe, tol = 0.01, gamma = 20).fit(X, Y)
```

Unfortunately I only have `v0.18`, which doesn't accept user-defined kernel functions for `LabelPropagation`, so I can't test it.

**EDIT2:**

Checking your source for why you have such large `gamma` values makes me wonder if you are using `gamma = D.min()/3`, which would be incorrect.  The definition is `sigma = D.min()/3` while the definition of `sigma` in `w` is

```
w = exp(-d**2/sigma**2)  # Equation (1)
```

which would make the correct `gamma` value `1/sigma**2` or `9/D.min()**2`

Comment: Why should you not change the *implementation*? You could inherit from `LabelPropagation`, and overwrite `_get_kernel` to use your custom `rbf_kernel`, in which you add a line `K -= K.max()` after [line 843](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f0ab589f/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py#L843) in the sklearn implementation. Disclaimer: haven't tested any of this.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I was thinking on doing my own kernel. And don't worry, I used gamma = 9/D.min()**2, which is big if D.min() < 1

Comment: Honestly the heuristic for `gamma` in that paper seems to be more of a WAG that worked for a given data set.  `gamma >>1` is very quickly going to get you a binary `label_distributions` matrix (with only 1s and 0s) and if any row gets driven to all 0's (becasue one point is far from any others) your method will fail as you've described.

Comment: Today I had time to try and the modified kernel allow me to work with bigger gamma than the classic rbf kernel. Thank's !